# How to create rotating bounding area while using Capture in EmguCv?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

My problem is as follows:

Using EmguCv (C# OpenCV) I have to write an application that can detect if my figure rotate or not using webcam in my computer. I used Capture to catch frames from my webcam. Also, I "cleaned" every frame using `SmoothGausian` and `Canny` filters. Thanks to that all what camera can see is my figure which I drew on a sheet of paper. I checked the `hu1` moment of my figure and while checking contours in my frame I pick only those which have similar `hu1` moment. And now it's the hardest part. While I start rotate my sheet of paper I want to count angle of this rotation. I figured out that I can use bounding area which is the square that surround found contour and I could calculate the angle of the lines (previous and present) between two points of this area. Unfortunately this bounding area does not rotate and now I ask you guys for help :) Does anyone know how to solve this problem :) ?

I'm sorry for such a novel, but I wanted to describe my problem thoroughly. In addition I attached part om my code where all of this drawing and catching frame are taking place.

```
//img - filtrated rame from a camera
var tmp = img.Convert<Gray, byte>().FindContours();

for (; tmp.HNext != null; tmp = tmp.HNext)
{
    if(tmp.GetMoments().GetHuMoment().hu1 > 0.325 && tmp.GetMoments().GetHuMoment().hu1 < 0.34)
    //if (tmp.GetMoments().GetHuMoment().hu1 > 0.33 && tmp.GetMoments().GetHuMoment().hu1 < 0.335)
    {
        var color1 = new Bgra(0, 255, 0, 255);
        drawImg.Draw(tmp, color1, 2);

        int left = tmp.BoundingRectangle.Left;
        int top = tmp.BoundingRectangle.Top;
        int right = tmp.BoundingRectangle.Right;

        Point[] line2 = { new Point(left, top), new Point(right, top) };
        drawImg.DrawPolyline(line2, false, new Bgra(255, 0, 0, 255), 1); 

        plik.WriteLine(left + "\t" + top);

        Point[] tab = tmp.ToArray();

        Point[] pointy = {tab[0], new Point( (int)tmp.GetMoments().GravityCenter.x, (int)tmp.GetMoments().GravityCenter.y )};

        Console.WriteLine(tab[0].ToString());

        drawImg.DrawPolyline(pointy, false, new Bgra(0, 0, 255, 255), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to see the image of a frame showing the detected figured. And another similar image, with the rotated figure inside it.

Comment: There you go https://www.dropbox.com/gallery/7104350/1/stack?h=b48a29#/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [template matching](http://nashruddin.com/template-matching-in-opencv-with-example.html) and [contour matching](http://amitsarangi.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/rotation-invariant-template-matching/). The native template matching provided by OpenCV doesn’t account for rotation and scaling.

On the first reference you'll find code for download and a bunch of useful comments on how to do detect rotation as well.

The second is an interesting blog post that discuss step-by-step how to do contour matching (a case of template matching invariant of rotation) and shares the source code that does the trick.

Both present C/C++ source code using OpenCV, so I imagine you'll have no problems translating them to C#.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate rotation between a reference figure and the one you acquire using your webcam I can suggest you to:

1. Extract the set of corners (***xi***) on reference image using emgucv harris-corner detector
2. Extract the set of corners (***yi***) on acquired frames still using emgucv harris corner detector
3. Compute *matches* between ***xi*** and ***yi*** using a simple matching strategy such as *[ZNCC](http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/tag/sum-of-squared-differences/)*
4. Compute a similarity transformation matrix ***T*** between noisy matches computed at steps number 3

The first three steps are quite simple and you can find code samples on google (search for opencv or emgucv harris corner detector).

I will give you some useful code extracted from my thesis for step number 4, that assume a similarity transform with isotropic scaling between your objects:

```
/// <summary>
    ///   Compute the similarity transformation between a set of noise correspondance matching pairs.
    ///   A similarity transformation has got 5 degrees of freedom:
    ///     - tx and ty for translation
    ///     - isotropic scaling s = Math.Sqrt (a^2 + b ^ 2)
    ///     - orientation = tan^-1 (b\a).
    ///     
    /// 
    ///        Similarity Matrix Transformation
    ///        
    ///   | x' |       |  a    -b     tx  |   | x |
    ///   | y' |   =   |  a     b     ty  | . | y |
    ///   | 1  |       |  0     0      1  |   | 1 | 
    ///              
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="matches">Putative Correspondance Pairs</param>
    /// <param name="homographyDirection">Direction of Transformation Estimation</param>
    /// <returns>Homography Matrix shaped as a Similarity Transformation</returns>
    public static HomographyMatrix GetSimilarityHomographyMatrixLeastSquares(MatchedImageFeature[] matches)
    {
        int n = matches.Length;
        Matrix<float> M = new Matrix<float>(2, 3);
        PointF[] srcPoints = new PointF[n];
        PointF[] dstPoints = new PointF[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                srcPoints[i] = matches[i].ObservedFeature.KeyPoint.Point;
                dstPoints[i] = matches[i].SimilarFeatures[0].Feature.KeyPoint.Point;
        }

        GCHandle handleSrcPts = GCHandle.Alloc(srcPoints, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Matrix<float> srcMatrix = new Matrix<float>(n, 1, 2, handleSrcPts.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 2 * sizeof(float));
        GCHandle handleDstPts = GCHandle.Alloc(dstPoints, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Matrix<float> dstMatrix = new Matrix<float>(n, 1, 2, handleDstPts.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 2 * sizeof(float));

        cvEstimateRigidTransform(srcMatrix, dstMatrix, M, 0);
        handleDstPts.Free();
        handleSrcPts.Free();


        double xScale, yScale;
        xScale = yScale= Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(M[0,0],2) + Math.Pow(M[0,1],2));
        double xOffset = M[0, 2];
        double yOffset = M[1, 2];
        double theta = Math.Atan(M[0, 1] / M[0, 0]) * (180 / Math.PI);

        HomographyMatrix similarityTransform = new HomographyMatrix();
        similarityTransform[0, 0] = M[0, 0];
        similarityTransform[0, 1] = M[0, 1];
        similarityTransform[0, 2] = M[0, 2];
        similarityTransform[1, 0] = M[1, 0];
        similarityTransform[1, 1] = M[1, 1];
        similarityTransform[1, 2] = M[1, 2];
        similarityTransform[2, 0] = 0;
        similarityTransform[2, 1] = 0;
        similarityTransform[2, 2] = 1;

        return similarityTransform;
    }
```